# Showing that $f_n \leq (7/4)^{n−1}$ where $f_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number (with $f_1=f_2=1$)

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

> We define the Fibonacci sequence via $f_1 = f_2 = 1$, and if $n > 2$, then $f_n = f_{n−1} + f_{n−2}$. Show that, for every positive integer $n$, $f_n \leq (7/4)^{n−1}$.

**My attempt**

I am using strong induction, and so far I have obtained this, am I ok?

For $n=1$, we have $f_1=1=(\frac{7}{4})^0$

For $n=2$, $f_2=1<\frac{7}{4}$

Now suppose that $f_n ≤ (7/4)^{n−1}$ for all $n>2$.

Then $f_n=f_{n−1} + f_{n−2}\leq (\frac{7}{4})^{n-2}+(\frac{7}{4})^{n-3}=(\frac{44}{49})(\frac{7}{4})^{n-1}<(\frac{7}{4})^{n-1}$.

Finishing the proof.

Comment: Yes that works.